# Xamarin Forms iOS - ImageView does not resize splash screen to different screen sizes after using constraints

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imageview, resize

I can't seem to find a way to resize the image view depending on the screen sizes in VS2017 using the iOS storyboard editor. The image is in the center of the iPhone X screen, but when viewing other screen layouts i.e. iPhone 8, the image is off center.

How do I achieve the resizing? Do I use the constraints for this purpose? If so then how?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout

Comment: You can use constraints, use + and try in phone and ipad.Here is a sample of how you have to do, those forms in the form of "T" subject a and drag to the edge of the screen.
*Video: Xamarin Evolve 2014: Dynamic Layout in iOS 8 - Adrian Stevens https://youtube.com/watch?v=f3mMGlS-lM4*

Comment: Thanks JohnHeaven, the information you provided helped me out. I got it to work in the end. Thanks again!